# another way to write this sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Environment: Sql Server 2008

have rows of a column that contains comma separated values.

what to get the row even if a single product exists in that csv.

this is how i can do it but was just wondering if another way to write it?

```
SELECT * FROM REWARDS
WHERE ProductCsv like '%banana%' 
   or ProductCsv like '%strawberry%' 
   or ProductCsv like '%orange%'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current query doesn't seem to accurately capture the results you want. What if we have a row like this:

```
bananaberry cream pie,strawberry shortcake,orange juice
```

Should this match your query or not? I think this would be more accurate:

```
WHERE ',' + ProductCsv + ',' LIKE '%,banana,%'
   OR ',' + ProductCsv + ',' LIKE '%,strawberry,%'
   OR ',' + ProductCsv + ',' LIKE '%,orange,%'
```

If you're just trying to find *one* item, this is probably much more efficient:

```
WHERE ',' + ProductCsv + ',' LIKE '%,banana,%'
```

You probably want to use a split function. For example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings_XML
(
   @List   NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delim  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   RETURN 
   (  
      SELECT Item = y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)')
      FROM 
      ( 
        SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' + REPLACE(@List, @Delim, '</i><i>') 
        + '</i>').query('.')
      ) AS a CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)
   );
GO
```

So now you can say:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.REWARDS AS r
WHERE EXISTS 
(
  SELECT 1 FROM dbo.REWARDS AS r2
  CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitStrings_XML(r2.ProductCsv, ',') AS x
  WHERE x.Item IN ('orange','strawberry','banana')
  AND r2.[key] = r.[key]
);
```

Or more simply:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.ProductCsv --, other columns
  FROM dbo.REWARDS AS r
  CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitStrings_XML(r.ProductCsv, ',') AS x
  WHERE x.Item IN ('orange','strawberry','banana');
```

The XML approach is a little brittle depending on the kinds of strings can be stored in the table, but there are many alternatives (including passing in your set via a TVP instead of as a list or separate values). For some much deeper background on split functions see these blog posts:

http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-follow-up

http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-now-with-less-t-sql

That all said, I don't know if this is any better than what you have now.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the following example using XML

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        CommaList VARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'banana,test,hello'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'homer,banana,test,hello'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'homer,banana'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '1,2,3'

;WITH XMLValues AS (
        SELECT  *,
                CAST('<d>' + REPLACE(CommaList, ',', '</d><d>') + '</d>' AS XML) XMLValue
        FROM    @Table t
)
, SplitValues AS (
        SELECT  xv.*,
                T2.Loc.value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)') SplitValue
        FROM    XMLValues xv
        CROSS APPLY XMLValue.nodes('/d') as T2(Loc) 
)
SELECT  DISTINCT
        CommaList
FROM    SplitValues
WHERE   SplitValue = 'banana'
```

[xml Data Type Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

[nodes() Method (xml Data Type)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

[value() Method (xml Data Type)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

[Using Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You could store all the values to be compared in a table

```
DECLARE @Product_list TABLE(
        products VARCHAR(50)
)

Insert into @Product_list values
('banana'),
('strawberry'),
('orange')

SELECT * FROM REWARDS
join @Product_list
on ProductCsv like '%'+products+'%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a split function (there are many around on the web) to split ProductsCsv into individual elements and then compare that against banana, strawberry etc.

Ideally, you wouldn't store CSV data in a column, but instead have a separate table for that.